# Where to find documentation for Thread class

Tags: multithreading, jmeter

In this [JMeter article](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/writing-jmeter-functions-in-groovy/) author is showing some examples with Thread class. He executes some specific methods for this class like: `getName()`, `getId()`. But there are no links to documentation for it.
Can someone please share a link to documentation where i can find about Thread class methods?

Google doesn't helped. The closest thing is https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterThread.html, but this isn't a class that I'm looking for (it doesn't has methods getName(), getId())

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is java's [Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html) class, JMeter is written in (pure) Java

> A thread is a thread of execution in a program. The Java Virtual Machine allows an application to have multiple threads of execution running concurrently.

Answer (score 0):

Check out these links

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html

for example

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/java-lang-thread-class-java/